# How do I test for homogeneity of regression in MANCOVA?

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity, assumptions, ancova, familywise-error

I am using a one-way independent MANCOVA with 4 dependent variables and a single covariate. My  predictor is bivariate. I'm currently trying to test for heterogeneity of regression in SPSS by assessing the interaction between the covariate and predictor. The question is whether I should test the interaction for each dependent variable at a time or for the MANCOVA model as a whole? Preliminarily, the interaction in the MANCOVA model is non-significant, while two of of the interactions in my multiple ANCOVA comparisons are significant. Currently this leaves me at an impasse. I believe the the multiple ANCOVA interactions will inflate the familywise error of finding significant heterogeneity – is this assumption correct?

Theoretically, I have reason to infer homogeneity of regression.